# Featured question appears twice on mobile iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, featured-tag

The featured meta question appears twice on the iOS app, pictured here:

[image]

It seems as if one link is showing the question at a previous time (and is not updated), given the mismatch in answer counts.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)